# Sequelize throw AssertionErrors with MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm building an API using nodejs, sequelize, dan MySQL database (10.1.21-MariaDB). When I tried to do some PATCHing (updating data), it throws AssertionErrors, but it works fine with POST (inserting data).

Here's my patch code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const brandModel = sequelize.define('tbl_brand', {
    brand_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
}, {
        freezeTableName: true,
});

router.patch('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const newModel = {
        brand_name: req.body.brand_name
    };

    sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
        const promise = brandModel.update(newModel, {brand_id: id});
        return promise.then(function(item){
            res.status(201).json({
                success: true,
                result: item
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            result: err
        });
    });
});
```

I use postman and access it like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/brand/1
```

With Raw JSON:

```
{
    "brand_name" : "Adidasssss"
}
```

And here's the result:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "result": {
        "generatedMessage": false,
        "name": "AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]",
        "code": "ERR_ASSERTION",
        "expected": true,
        "operator": "=="
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I was careless, I was updating an empty instance called brandModel. It should be searched first then do the update